# How to add dynamic variable to API link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing a problem that I want to make my API link as dynamic by passing variable to it. My API is: http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=SGD,MYR 
Now I want last two value i.e SGD & MYR as dynamic variable from input field what I entered. So how to do this ? 
Here is my full code.

```js
$(function(){
   $('button').on('click' , function(){
      var val1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
      var val2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;

      var $records = $('#records');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET' ,
               url: "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols="+val2+","+val1,  //value are not coming to the link 
               success: function(data) 
               {
                   console.log(val1);      // values are coming here
            console.log(val2);     // values are coming here
             var rate1 = data.rates.val1 ;
            var rate2 = data.rates.val2 ;
            var final = rate1/rate2 ;
            $('#records').html ('Total Rate for Above Currency is :  ' + final ) ;
               }
            });
        });
   });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body align="center"><br/><br/><br/>
<h1> Welcome Currency Convertor </h1> <br/><br/>
Local CCY : <input type="text" id="value1"> <br/><br/>
Hotel CCY : <input type="text" id="value2"> <br/><br/>
<button> Show rate </button> <br/><br/>
<div id="records"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us a valid API request? What kind of values are `val1`and `val2`?

Comment: If I write Rahul in input field 1 and sinha in input field 2 then the link will be like that : "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=Rahul,sinha",

Comment: A valid API request : http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=SGD,MYR

Comment: Seems to be working in the code snippet now

Comment: No, It's not working put MYR and SGD in both input fields and hit show rate, which doesn't make the API url as : http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=SGD,MYR . so, the total rate is not showing. It shows NaN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    var $records = $('#records');
    var composedUrl = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=" + val1 + "," + val2;

    console.log(composedUrl);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: composedUrl,
      success: function(data) {

        var rate1 = data.rates[val1];
        var rate2 = data.rates[val2];

        console.log(rate1);
        var final = rate1 / rate2;
        $('#records').html('Total Rate for Above Currency is :  ' + final);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body align="center"><br/><br/><br/>
  <h1> Welcome Currency Convertor </h1> <br/><br/> Local CCY : <input type="text" id="value1"> <br/><br/> Hotel CCY : <input type="text" id="value2"> <br/><br/>
  <button> Show rate </button> <br/><br/>
  <div id="records"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, Great this work for me, but then too there is one thing remaining. var rate1 = data.rates.val1;  by doing this-> console.log(rate1); it shows undefined. but when I write var rate1 = data.rates.MYR; it gives value. why this is not giving that value ?

Comment: I've updated the code. You were referencing the object key with val1 and val2 and it was trying to find that keys on the object which in fact were `SGD`and `MYR`. Check the changes: `var rate1 = data.rates[val1];` instead of `var rate1 = data.rates.val1;` will make the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the last +, like this:

```
url: "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols="+val1+","+val2,
```

Because nothing comes after it.
Now it expects another variable or string, but there is none

Comment: Yes, it work but when I passing variable to the API link , they are not taking that value in link what I used in input field.

Comment: url: "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols="+val1+","+val2, In this values are not coming to the url. How to do this ?